# How to pass a field from the Main UI as an argument for a method from different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am writing a program using c# and Wpf. I call the methods that perform my calculations in a different thread to keep the App responsive , however when I try to pass a field from the main thread as an argument for those methods from a different thread I get an exception. I've tried using Dispatcher it didn't solve my problem.Here's the method that is called in the different thread:

```
        private void Compare()
    {
        //gets a hashcode using getpixel string instance and checks if image is cropped using CompareStrings method of check instance
        BitmapImage Image1 = new BitmapImage();
        BitmapImage Image2 = new BitmapImage();
        Action a = () =>
        {
            Image1.UriSource = image1.UriSource;
            Image2.UriSource = image2.UriSource;
        };
        Dispatcher.Invoke(a);
             hashcode1 = getPixel.GetHashCode(Image1);
             hashcode2 = getPixel.GetHashCode(Image2);
             bool match = check.CompareStrings(hashcode2, hashcode1);
             if (match)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("The image is Cropped");
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("These are two different images");
             }


    }
```

Here's code that calls thread:

```
        private void CompareButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(Compare);
        workerThread.Start();
    }
```

Here's a code for a GetHashCode method, that's where I get an exception:

```
public List<string> GetHashCode(BitmapImage bitmap)
    {//takes a bitmap and translates it into the hashcode list
        List<string> hashCode= new List<string>();

        int stride = bitmap.PixelWidth * (bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.PixelHeight; i++)//divides an image into rows 
        {
            string row="";
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.PixelWidth; x++)//iterates through each pixel in the row
            {
                byte[] pixel = new byte[bitmap.PixelHeight];//holds color values of a single pixel
                bitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, i, 1, 1), pixel, stride, 0);//assigns color values of a single pixel to the pixel array
                Color singlePixel = new Color();//creates new color objects and assigns the color values found in pixel array to it
                singlePixel.B = pixel[0];
                singlePixel.G = pixel[1];
                singlePixel.R = pixel[2];
                singlePixel.A = pixel[3];
                row += singlePixel.GetHashCode().ToString();//converst the color value into the hashcode and converts it to the string
            }
            hashCode.Add(row);
            UpdatePRogress();
        }
```

As you see I tried using Dispatcher  method but it didn't work

Comment: What is the exception, and what line is it on?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend creating a copy of the BitmapImages you're working with (possibly as `Bitmap` objects) and work with them in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use BackgroundThreads for UI related activities. Try Changing your code like this.

```
    private void CompareButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker workerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerThread.DoWork+=workerThread_DoWork;
        workerThread.RunWorkerCompleted +=workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted;
        workerThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void workerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process completed");
    }

    private void workerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Compare();
    }

    private void Compare()
    {
        //your method
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using background worker as Kosala Suggested however it still hasn't  solved my problem, then after googling a bit more I found out that you can pass an argument to the RunWorkerAsync() and then use it in your Do_Work Class, so what I did was I passed two string values that contain adrresses to the bitmap images to the RUnWorkerAsync and then used them to create  new instances of Bitmap images and then I passed those two new instances as an arguments to my functions. Solution looks a bit dirty to me , but I couldn't find a better one , so here's my Do_Work method:

```
 void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> strings = (List<string>)e.Argument;
        string string1 = strings[0];
        string string2 = strings[1];
        BitmapImage image1 = new BitmapImage();
        image1.BeginInit();
        image1.UriSource = new Uri(string1);
        image1.EndInit();

        BitmapImage image2 = new BitmapImage();
        image2.BeginInit();
        image2.UriSource = new Uri(string2);
        image2.EndInit();
        Compare(image1, image2);
    }
```